# Разрешить элемент в .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, robots.txt

для продвижения в поисковиках нужно настроить файл robots.txt. Я настроил, но так как у меня есть важные файлы в .txt формате, я его закрыл в .htaccess
Помогите сделать исключение для robots.txt, ну или разрешить robots.txt, короче что угодно, но лишь бы можно было зайти поисковикам в этот файл.
.htaccess:

```
<FilesMatch "\.txt$">
  Order Deny,Allow
  Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.log$">
  Order Deny,Allow
  Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Йоу, бро!

Зацени такой вариант:

```
<FilesMatch "(?<!robots)\.txt$">
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: Респект за подгон!

Comment: добавить вместо запрета на открытие тхт, или как отдельное условие?

Comment: @Dolphesy заменить `<FilesMatch "\.txt$">` тем, что у меня в ответе.